# why can't I see the decoded string?

Tags: python-3.x, base64, decode

I have a base64 string and I'm trying to figure out what it was, but I can't see anything. What am I doing wrong? Is this

```
>>> import base64
>>> b = base64.b64decode("FAAAAAMAAAAGAAAACQAAAAwAAAA=")
>>> b
b'\x14\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00'
>>> print(b.decode("utf16"))


>>> print(b.decode("utf8"))


>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It it is Base 64 encoding then it is not UTF-16 encoding, nor UTF-8. Have a look at [RFC 3548](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3548.html). The Base 64 can be found at page 4 of the document.

Acually, the very purpose is different. The UTF-x encodings are here to encode a unicode string into a binary stream. That is, the abstract string is the decoded form. On the other hand, Base X and the like encodings are here to *encode* the original binary into a stream of selected ASCII values (basically small integers) so that the binary content could be transfered via e-mail that accepts only characters. The binary is the decoded, original form.

In your case, it looks that as if the serie of integers (32-bit) was transfered: 20, 3, 6, 9, and 12.

*Updated later to answer the comment below:* How I got the values...

```
b'\x14\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00'
```

The `b` prefix of the literal says it is the literal with the `bytes` type value. The `bytes` is a stream of small integers -- each of one byte, that is from zero to 255. When displayed as the literals, the hexadecimal notation of the small integers is used if the related ASCII character cannot be easily displayed -- starting with `\x` followed by two hexadecimal numerals. The `\t` is the representation of the tab character which has the ordinal value 9.

However, you can also convert it to the list of integers:

```
>>> list(b)
[20, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 6, 0, 0, 0, 9, 0, 0, 0, 12, 0, 0, 0]
```

Now it is more apparent. The zero is the filler if the values are small enough to fit into a single byte. The order of bytes is caused by endianness of the OS/machine. So, actually, it should be hexa (as five 32-bit integers):

```
00000014 00000003 00000006 00000009 0000000c
```

Which is:

```
      20        3        6        9       12
```

In other words, the `b'\x14\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x00\x00\x06\x00\x00\x00\t\x00\x00\x00\x0c\x00\x00\x00'` is actually not a string. It is a `bytes` literal that captures the value of 5 * 4 bytes. The `bytes` is a sequence of small integers, not of characters. It is more apparent when you try:

```
>>> for value in b:
...     print(value)
...    
20
0
0
0
3
0
0
0
6
0
0
0
9
0
0
0
12
0
0
0
>>> type(b)
<class 'bytes'>
>>> type(b[0])
<class 'int'>
>>>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please show me how did you get the integer values from that string? I'm trying to make some sense out of that string encoded in base 64.

Comment: Should the 20 be associated with the total number of integers in the encoded string?

Comment: It is not a string. It is `bytes` value. Anyway, the `20` is definitely *not* Python related. The original string is simply a string, the result of `base64.b64decode` is a sequence of bytes. My interpretation that the values could be five 32-bit integers is just speculation. It is your-problem related. I do not know how exactly the value should be interpreted.